# When connecting to ethernet it's shutting down/crashing

Tags: hardware, power-supply

A few days ago I connected my Raspberry Pi to my screen and I did some work directly on it (without GUI, thus only command line) and suddenly it crashed / shutdown.

The red light is on all the time. Today I tried with a bit of trial and error and I tried to run it with ethernet and power source connected, it happened again. Then I tried to connect almost everything except ethernet (mouse, keyboard and power). Then it stayed on-line all the time (a few hours) then I added the ethernet cable and it then after a few minutes crashed with only the red light appearing. (I can see from the light in my mouse (red laser light) that it was on before and then when I connected it to the ethernet it, after a while, didn't show its red laser light anymore. I also tried to reinstall Raspbian, didn't help.

Has anyone ever tried anything like this? Does the Raspberry Pi keep a failure log in which I could look at? Or anything else?

**Update**-I tried using another power source ( a garmin charger supplying 1A ) and yet again the pi crashed after sometime.So we can possibly rule out this being a power issue.

Comment: How is your Pi being powered and have you overclocked it?

Comment: I have not overclocked it. I memory splitted (32 to GPU) and expanded its roots. I am powering it through an Apple iPhone charger and a usb->micro USB cable.

Comment: What is the output power of that iPhone charger?

Comment: 5V == 1A, which should be alright, shouldn't it?

Comment: @mikkeljuhl 1A should be alright.However, you should test with another power source before ruling that out.A lot of [Fake apple chargers](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/2151) have already caused trouble with pi.

Comment: It's an original Apple charger though. But I will test it out, can you use your computer to power it? (As I have heard you shouldn't do that.

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to use your computer to power it since most of the USB ports cannot supply upwards of 500mA,possibly even a lot less than that.

Comment: I just found a Garmin charger for a watch, which also had 5V == 1A output, I logged in to my Raspberry and then did apt-get update, which worked fine. Then I did the apt-get upgrade and while it was working on that it crashed. So I think we can rule out the adapter's fault, unfortunately.

Comment: I think your Pi is borked :( You might have to return it for a replacement.

Comment: @mikkeljuhl Any new developments with your pi?

Comment: I have had it shut down from the 14th till now, I will try with a new ethernet cable and see what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was doing something similar but I found the cause.

1) The Ethernet cable I was using had a broken clip, and so the plug kept slipping out. All the other lights go off, because they are all to do with the link status.  If the cable is disconnected, there is no link so only the red power-light stays on.  Mine however didn't crash, I just pushed the plug fully home and all was restored.

2) If your Ethernet connection is supplying power over Ethernet (Mine does as I have VoIP phones) that can cause you a few hiccups, shouldn't be anything major though.

Sounds to me mostly like the plug is coming loose, loosing the connection then some app expecting the connection / link to be there is bringing the OS down when the connection is lost.